# asp.net ashx handlers session timeout and jquery ajax calls

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i'm developing a web form application in asp.net and using jquery ajax calls for most of the operations. for server oprations i'm using ashx handlers.

my issue is when the user's session expire (after some time of inactivicty), and the user click a button which makes a jquery ajax call, how to detect from handler that session expired and return a specific json.

a [similar qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006084/managing-session-timeouts-in-asp-net-when-using-asp-net-generichandlers) but doesn't have a proper answer.

thanks in advance.

rgds
Rifky

Comment: This question shows that you have not looked around before asking. Here is a similar question that might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856553/how-to-get-asp-net-session-value-in-jquery-method)

Comment: @Ahmad-San, i searched for a similer one but couldnt find a answer. there was one [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006084/managing-session-timeouts-in-asp-net-when-using-asp-net-generichandlers) but no proper answer. any how. the link you have provided is to check the session valus using jquery. but my issue is, if the session expired and a ajax request is fired, i need to check the session expired in handler.

Comment: @Ahmad-San, that shows that i have searched the web before asking that question, so a -1 for the question is not fair

Comment: I tried to remove the -1 but the site tells me that the question must be edited first. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: please can i get any response :-(

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to check to see if your session has expired for any ashx in your global.asax file. If it has, return a json session expired object. On the client side, you would then check to see if that object exists and redirect the user to the login page via javascript.

So in your global.asax file you would have something like the following:

```
   protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(url);
        if (extension == ".ashx" && HttpContext.Current.Session.Contents.Count == 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 440;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(new JObject(new JProperty("sessionExpired")).ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Then you would create a global ajax event error handler for all of your ajax queries that looks for the "sessionExpired" object:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr, settings)
{
    if (xhr.responseText && $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText).sessionExpired)
    {
        window.location.replace("loginUrl.aspx");
        return;
    }
});
```

The good thing about this approach is that you only have to have these two snippets of code in order to get reasonable session expiration handling. However, there is a downside to this approach:

All of your ashx files must at least have the IReadOnlySessionState or IRequiresSessionState interfaces. Otherwise, the session expired logic will be triggered since the session will be assumed to be null. If you don't want this, then you need a way to exclude certain .ashx files, such as excluding any urls that contain a certain path that contains your ashx files.

In addition, if there are certain parts of your page that do not involve using the session, then you will need to exclude those pages as well.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It helps me